# about moving files to another directory

Tags: java

```
 child.move(source,target, REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

I am trying to move files(childs) to different directory. It says
move is undefined for file type File. Why is it outputting this?
If it can't be fixed, what other methods exist?

Comment: Try to put meaningful code. What is the type of child? what is File? what is the error ?

Comment: @moonwave99 no, this is no duplicate; since there is `Files` now, SO users should be "reeducated" as to anything file-related in Java :p

Comment: @fge - the problem is, even though we all know J6 is EOL, in the real world you can't rely on being able to use J7. There are places that still use J5 ::sigh::

Answer (score 2):

> Why is it outputting this?

Because `File` has no such method...

> If it can't be fixed, what other methods exist?

On `File` there is `.renameTo()` (but it's broken -- returns a boolean, cannot cross filesystem boundaries), but use Java 7's [`Files.move()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) instead which has none of `File`'s drawbacks.